# Changing TextToDisplay for Hyperlinks in Excel via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Goal:
Replace the display text for any hyperlinks in an Excel sheet starting with [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) with [Google](https://www.google.com) while maintaining the original hyperlink URL and cell position.

I'm bashing together what I found online, like [How To Change Multiple Hyperlink Paths At Once In Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1437-excel-change-multiple-hyperlinks.html).

I feel I'm close with:

```vb
Sub ReplaceHyperlinks()
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim xHyperlink As Hyperlink
Set Ws = Application.ActiveSheet
For Each xHyperlink In Ws.Hyperlinks
    xHyperlink.TextToDisplay = Replace(xHyperlink.TextToDisplay, "www.google.com/*", "Google")
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I assume each link is different so you can't use `replace`. Use `texttodisplay` like you have first then use `find`+`mid` after that.

Comment: Yes each link is different, I had hopes the wildcard ("www.google.com/*") would account for the different links.

Comment: They are all google? Then just use find+mid. Edit: actually, find+mid should make it text anyways so you can skip texttodisplay.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do a little research on those functions and give it a try.

Comment: Are your links actual hyperlinks (Insert >> link) or are they using `=HYPERLINK()` ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `mid` and `find` like

```
=MID(A1,5,FIND(".",A1,5)-5)
```

Edit:
So use `hyperlink` like

```
=HYPERLINK(B1,PROPER(B1))
```

[image]

Comment: I see. Maybe I was unclear.    
   
I still need the actual hyperlink to be a hyperlink to the same URL as it originally was.    
   
I'm just looking to change the text displayed for that hyperlink so all of them are identical. So once the VBA script was run [https://www.google.com/test](https://www.google.com/test) would become [Google](https://www.google.com/test)

Comment: See edit.......

Comment: The reason I was looking to VBA and not visible formule like that is so I avoid having to have multiple untidy columns. Running a script to change the actual displayed text of the original hyperlink and not creating a new cell entry all together would mean the data can be entered and then tidied without anyone needing to hide and unhide columns. The aim is someone can enter multiple urls, hit a macro button and the original cell is edited to change the hyperlink display text.

Comment: Gotcha. You should be able to modify my formulas into code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```vb
Sub ReplaceHyperlinks()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim lnk As Hyperlink
    Set Ws = Application.ActiveSheet
    For Each lnk In Ws.Hyperlinks
        If LCase(lnk.Address) Like "*google.com*" Then 'Google link ?
            lnk.TextToDisplay = "Google"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your architecture is always better than mine ^_^

Comment: Yeah looks good. I'd just add something that works for multiple links like `lnk.TextToDisplay = StrConv(Split(lnk.Address, ".")(1), vbProperCase)`

Comment: What about `https://google.com` though ?  It's not so simple to create a generalized approach...

Comment: Just an idea... But yeah, your right depends on how complex the URL is. Just have to make more logic.

Comment: Wonderful thank you very much that does the job. I'll pick it apart a bit for better understanding.